# Error while searching for the latest file is a directory using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am trying to create a batch file to find the newest file in a directory. I am using the following commands in the batch:

```
call cd\
call d:
call cd "D:\OMS\Outbound\"
call for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%G in ('dir /b /od') do set newest=%%G
call pause
```

I am getting the error `G was unexpected at this time`.

Also I would like to ftp the newest file and will have to append `"local:D:\OMS\Outbound\"` before `%%G` in the following manner `newest=local:D:\OMS\Outbound\%G`. 
The code works just fine when run from command prompt but the batch file is not working.

Comment: first, remove  **all** heading `call`s in every line.

Answer (score 3):

```
cd /d "D:\OMS\Outbound"
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /od') do set "newest=local:D:\OMS\Outbound\%%~G"
echo %newest%
pause
```

and remove other lines.

Comment: Thanks @Endoro. It worked. Could you please tell me why my commands did not give the required results?

Comment: there is no need for `call`, see also `call /?` on the command line.

Comment: add `/a-d` to the DIR switches to stop any directory names being included.

Comment: @foxidrive thnx. I was looking for that as well.

Comment: That's ok.  `tokens=` is most valuable when splitting up a string into sections.  `"delims="` takes the entire line.  The ~ in `%%~G` is not needed here but it doesn't cause any issue. It's used to remove any surrounding double quotes on the variable.

Comment: OK @Endoro .  Will do. But why did you remove token=* and add ~ in %%~G? Thnx

Comment: @foxidrive yes I removed ~ and it is working. thnx. I just wanted to know where i went wrong when using the tokens=* in the bat file. Doesn't that mean that it should take the entire line? it was working when i was running from cmd

Comment: You had conflicting commands with tokens=* and delims= ".  While it may work, and only for filenames with no leading spaces, it was confusing syntax.  Tokens=* strips leading whitespace.